# Anypoint Studio 6.4 becomes unresponsive on OS X BigSur 11.3.1

Tags: java-8, mule, anypoint-studio, macos-big-sur, adoptopenjdk

Since I have updated to BigSur 11.3.1 AnypointStudio 6.4 starts, but it became unresponsive to the mouse or the keyboard. I tried with fresh install, upgrade the jdk8 to the latest, and even installing the Anypoint Studio 6.6

I can't see anything on the app logs or in the System log.

I have tested exactly the same installation on BigSur 11.3.0, and everything works fine.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studio 6 until Studio 6.6.7 (the last release of Studio 6 available at this time) have some issues with macOS Big Sur. The latest version of Studio 7 doesn't has that problem, though it is not compatible with Mule 3.x. The problem is that the older Studio 6 is based on Eclipse libraries that are not compatible with the latest macOS. You'll need to wait for a newer release of Studio 6 that fixes the compatibility.

Update:
Studio 6.6.8 resolves the issues with macOS Big Sur: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-6.6-with-3.9.4-runtime-update-site-8-release-notes

Comment: I heard about, what is odd is that 6.4 with 11.3.0 works perfectly well. Any forecast when it will be available?

Comment: The new version has been released. I have updated my answer with the details.